# Video upload file error

Tags: php, file, types, upload, error-handling

I have an upload video form that works perfectly when upload a small avi file.  This is my php code used to place the video in a folder of my choice

```
$path = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$ext = $path['extension'];
if ($ext == "avi" || $ext == "mp4" || $ext == "mpg" || $ext == "mov" || $ext == "wmv" || $ext == "flv"){
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else{
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";        
        if (file_exists("videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            echo "<a href = './videochannel.php'>Return to Channel</a>";
        }
        else{
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
              echo "Stored in: " . "videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
              echo "<a href = './videochannel.php'>Return to Channel</a>";
        }
    }
}
else{
    echo "That is not a supported file type. Please try again.  <a href = './videochannel.php'>Return to Channel</a>";
}
?>
```

But when I upload an mp4 I get  " return code 1 " which if im not mistaken has to do with the max upload size which i have changed to 200M in my php.ini. It still didn't work. This also has says it is not a supported file type when uploading any of the other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i didn't restart my server

Answer (score 0):

Return 1 occurs when your uploaded file exceeds the maximum size set by the php.ini
check out this maybe it works for u

Comment: i changed like literally to 20000000000M to see if it would work and still nothin

Answer (score 0):

i guess 1mb is a limit for upload by default make it 20mb for a test and upload a file of maximum 20mb file and check it

Comment: in the php.ini i made it 700M so it should be good but it still gives my code 1